# Arc reversal problem for tournaments and Ádám conjecture

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

I'm trying to understand the next proof

[image]

I don't understand the way the author chooses the set $S$, I mean, which is the criterion? I've been thinking in two possibilities:

1. The only possible arcs from $S$ to V(T)-S are $<x,w>,<x,z>$ or $<x,v>$, but this contadicts what he says next that $S\cup \{w\}$ contradicts the maximality of $S$.

2.The only possible arcs from $S$ to $V(T)-S$ have their head on $z,w$ or $v$, of course if the belong to $V(T)-S$. About this one, it is true that $S\cup \{w\}$ contradicts the maximality of $S$ but the existence of $w_1\in V(T)-S$ which dominates $w$, not necessarily fixes that, unless there is another vertex in $V(T)-S$ dominated by $w$, more over, in this way $S\cup \{w_1\}$ also contradicts the maximality of $S$ unless ther exists another vertex in $V(T)-S$ dominated by $w_1$.

Perhaps I'm missunderstanding the idea about $S$, so I need your help here, I see something weird in this proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I, too, don't see how $S \cup \{w\}$ contradicts the maximality of $S$. In particular, $S$ was maximal with respect to a complicated property including the requirement that $z,w,v \notin S$. So $S \cup \{w\}$ is *not* among the sets in which $S$ is maximal, and we can't conclude anything about it from the maximality of $S$.

Comment: It also seems weird to explicitly include "the reversal of these three arcs results in a tournament that is not strongly connected" as a hypothesis. Once we reverse these three arcs, we get a tournament in which $\operatorname{od}(x) = 0$, so of course it is not strongly connected!

Comment: @MishaLavrov exactly, in deed, it is very weird what the author does. The other hypothesis may will be used later in the proof, but I didn't include it completely beacuase I can't move forward with this mistake I wrote about. Thanks for your time and if you want to see the complete "proof" I can include it

Comment: I did find the proof online, it has the fairly unique feature of containing the words "strongly connncted" (with the typo). It didn't help me understand what's going on and it's possible that this is actually a mistake in the proof.

Comment: @MishaLavrov What I find weird is that nobody, neither the OP nor you, is willing to reveal the source or author of "Theorem 4.12".

Comment: @bof [Here's](https://scholarworks.lib.csusb.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=1409&context=etd) the place where I found it.

Comment: -1 for keeping secret the source of the quotation.

Comment: @MishaLavrov OK, thanks.

Comment: Could "these three arcs" mean (confusingly) the arcs of the transitive subtournament induced by $\{z,v,w\}$?

Comment: @bof nobody put anything in secret, It would be enough to ask for it as I commented, sorry, I don't know how to quote on this platform. However, how would your question answer mine?

Comment: I shouldn't have to ask for it, there was no reason to omit the author's name in the first place. I never said the answer to my question (source of the quotation) would answer your quotation, but it's just possible there might be some more hints in the larger context.

Comment: There does seem to be something wrong with the definition of $S$ in that proof. Maybe I'm being stupid, but it seems to me that that definition implies that $S=V(T)-\{v,w,z\}$.